# splunk is reporting each line of stacktrace as a separate event

Tags: java, splunk

Our splunk instance is showing each line of a java stacktrace as a separate event.

[image]

Can we fix it without changing our java code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The paucity of information about the events make it hard to be specific about the solution.  You need to update the props.conf settings for that sourcetype so the multiple lines of the traceback are merged into a single event.  There are a number of ways to do that, including `SHOULD_LINEMERGE=true` and `BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE_DATE=true`.